# Want to echo variable value submitted to url by different request

Tags: php, url, httprequest

What I want to do is that as follows:

I sending the variable to the server `http://www.example.com/sample.php?id=123` using get method, on that page I wrote an code

```
$var=$_GET['id']  
echo $var;
```

but it's not working.

Please help on this issue. How can I echo the variable value which is submitted by other code? Or is there any way to store that variable to some file when request made to server?

Comment: use `$var=$_GET['id']; echo $var;` you have missed out semicolon

Comment: Seems like u missed a semicolon after all..

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Then he should've got an error, **if** error reporting is on.. but seems like a colon issue though...

Comment: @Mr.Alien, `but it's not working.` Maybe that was the error that he forgot to mention.

Comment: I used it sir, what I want to do is that suppose your making request to one page by using url by sending the variable with value using get request and I wrote the code on that page $var=$_GET['id']; echo $var; and when the request made to this page and next when I'm refreshing the page it's not showing any data

I'm not confirm that is to save the variable value in the variable on that page needs POST or GET request

Answer (score 1):

As people in the comments already said, you're missing a semicolon after the `]`.
You should have gotten an error, but apparently you have not.

During development, it is recommendable to turn on full error reporting. To do this, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script.

If you're bugged by all the **notices** and don't care to fix those minor issues, do `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` instead.

Comment: Please post your whole script.

Comment: Sir what I'm doing here is that from the application installed on my android phone will send one variable value to the url like www.example.com/sample.php?var=123 using get request and after he made request to that page . The code written in that page is var=$_GET['id']; echo $var; but it's not showing the output

Comment: Page which sending the request:-
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://www.sample.org/sample.php', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->setOptions(array('id' =>'23')));

try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        file_put_contents('sample.php', $r->getResponseBody());
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
?>

Comment: please help me all programmers , I'm the beginner

Answer (score 0):

seems like you missed the semicolon after the first line of code. if your error reporting is off in php ini file then u will probably get a blank page. hope that's the problem in your code.

```
$var=$_GET['id']; 
echo $var;
```

Comment: Page which sending the request:- <?php $r = new HttpRequest('sample.org/sample.php';, HttpRequest::METH_GET); $r->setOptions(array('id' =>'23'))); try { $r->send(); if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) { file_put_contents('sample.php', $r->getResponseBody()); } } catch (HttpException $ex) { echo $ex; } ?>

Comment: if you are sending it from an android device then u better try receiving the data using $var=$_REQUEST['id']; echo $var; hope this will work for you.

Comment: sir can you confirm me that the request sending from android device is require get or post if I want to save it into the variable on that page....

Comment: sir your the only hope for me

Comment: iam not clearly understanding your question. are u sending data from a android native app ? or from a webview ?

Comment: I downloaded app in android and from that app I'm sending the variable to url

Comment: and in that url which is nothing but to the php file in that file I added the code below <?php  $var = $_REQUEST['id']; echo $var ?> but it's not working